# Store assigned variable name of dataset in function

Tags: r

I want to dynamically use the variable name of any dataset within a function. The catch is that it has to work within any `loop` and `paste` function because I want to iterate the name over each row of data. Quite naturally, if I do this:

```
some_fun <- function(data){
print(substitute(data))
}
some_fun(teengamb)
>"teengamb"
```

Then It works and I get the result that I want. However, If I were to do the following:

```
some_fun <- function(data){
  print(map(data, function(x)paste(x,",",substitute(data))))
}
some_fun(gamble_formula)

>$formulas
 [1] "gamble ~ status , data"                         "gamble ~ sex , data"                           
 [3] "gamble ~ status + income , data"                "gamble ~ verbal + sex , data"                  
 [5] "gamble ~ sex + status , data"                   "gamble ~ status + income + verbal , data"      
 [7] "gamble ~ income + verbal + sex , data"          "gamble ~ verbal + sex + status , data"         
 [9] "gamble ~ sex + status + income , data"          "gamble ~ status + income + verbal + sex , data"
```

I should have 'gamble_formula', appended rather than 'data'. Here's the example data I am working with:

```
structure(list(formulas = c("gamble ~ status", "gamble ~ sex", 
"gamble ~ status + income", "gamble ~ verbal + sex", "gamble ~ sex + status", 
"gamble ~ status + income + verbal", "gamble ~ income + verbal + sex", 
"gamble ~ verbal + sex + status", "gamble ~ sex + status + income", 
"gamble ~ status + income + verbal + sex")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `eval`.

```
some_fun <- function(data) {
 d <- substitute(data)
 paste0(eval(d)$formulas, ', ', d)
}
some_fun(gamble_formula)
# [1] "gamble ~ status, gamble_formula"                         "gamble ~ sex, gamble_formula"                           
# [3] "gamble ~ status + income, gamble_formula"                "gamble ~ verbal + sex, gamble_formula"                  
# [5] "gamble ~ sex + status, gamble_formula"                   "gamble ~ status + income + verbal, gamble_formula"      
# [7] "gamble ~ income + verbal + sex, gamble_formula"          "gamble ~ verbal + sex + status, gamble_formula"         
# [9] "gamble ~ sex + status + income, gamble_formula"          "gamble ~ status + income + verbal + sex, gamble_formula"
```

Comment: storing `substitute(data)` into a separate variable does the trick for me!